# При запуске linux через устоновочную флешку (выдаёт ошибку)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, bios, uefi

Я пробовал всё что можно было попробовать. Secure boot отключён. Флешка: kingston 60gb
UEFI bios

[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите ваши попытки исправить проблему и опишите саму проблему более подробно.

Comment: вопрос для вас сложный.  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/something-has-gone-seriously-wrong-import_mok_state-failed-4175665926/   попробуйте другой дистрибутив, linuxmint, fedora, opensuse

Comment: предположение. вам нужно увеличить раздел /efi примерно 300-500мб. и, соответственно переразметить жесткий диск.

Comment: и вот это посмотрите, может что-то упустили https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPJk3PaFpa0